# Python import package with and without it's namespace

Tags: python, import, package

I have a package called `sound` with a directory structure like so:

```
sound/
|-- __init__.py
|-- interpreter.py
|-- blast.py
```

Before I had the package, `interpreter.py` would import `blast.py` with the command `import blast`. Now with the package I have to say `import sound.blast as blast`.

While I don't mind this, I'd like to be able to both import the `sound` package outside of it's directory with that statement, but also to run `interpreter.py` directly. But if I run `interpreter.py` directly, I get an import error saying that `sound` doesn't exist.

My current solution is something like this:

```
try:
    import sound.blast
except ImportError:
    import blast
```

But this feels ugly. Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: Why do you want to be able to run interpreter.py directly?

Comment: For flexibility I guess. It's not a big deal since I prefer the package and namespace, but I can imagine a scenario where someone tries to use my package and can't figure out how to use it because they try to run interpreter.py directly.

Comment: I don't think that use case is important enough that you should want to do this.

Comment: I also have a command line arguments for the interpreter. I don't want to always be importing the package. I want users to be able to run it with command line args.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another work around would be.

Replace the "try import" statement by the following lines into the interpreter.py file.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")

import sound.blast
```

Hence the parent directory will also be included in the path, then importing sound.blast within the sound directory wouldn't be a problem any more.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The `sys.path.append("..")` method actually didn't work properly for more complicated namespaces in my program. The best way I solved it was:

```
if __package__ == 'sound':  
    import sound.blast  
else:  
    import blast
```

Then more complicated namespaces worked, such as `sound.blast.driver.specification`